# Complex Analysis Limits

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Hi there. I am struggling to understand how the this equation is obtained in the working:

[image]

How do you approach along a line when working out a limit?

Thanks

Comment: If a function is differentiable it means that the limit exists along every continuous curve going to that point and **all** such limits are equal. They choose that line because it simplifies computation for them.

Comment: I just dont really understand how they get 1+i from that. Is there any chance you could show me explicitly?

Comment: They *don't* get $1+i$ from $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x+ix)-f(0)}{x+ix}$. **If** the function were differentiable, they *would* get that result. They don't, so the function is not differentiable.

Comment: @ArchieJudd the limit you asked for is below.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$

We note that functions being differentiable means a certain limit exists. Limits, by their nature, must be the same along every path going through the point if they are to exist at all, so they opt to check the path $y=x$ as one possibility. You work it out by using the facts about the line in question.

On **this** line they choose $y=x$ so we can replace $y$ with $x$ everywhere in the limit we see it and the limit becomes

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{1\over x+ix}{(1+i)x^3-(1-i)x^3\over x^2+x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}{1\over x+ix}{x^{\cancel{3}}((1+i)-(1-i))\over 2\cancel{x^2}}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}{2i\cancel{x}\over \cancel{x}(1+i)}=1+i$$

The last equality being easily observed as $(1+i)^2=1^2+2i+i^2=2i$